# How to jump next tag when using tagbar in VIM

Tags: vim, tagbar

when using VIM with tagbar displayed.
I want to use the next command in `.vimrc`

```
nnoremap tn <C-w>h<cr>
```

to jump to the next tag in the tagbar. But the it takes no effect at all.

when i typed tn, the cusor is jumped to the next tag, but the main window keeps still

is there somebody can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, `<CR>` in normal mode just moves the cursor to the beginning of the next line. To make that key jump to the tag on the current line, the *tagbar* plugin defines a buffer-local mapping in its tag window. Though it's generally recommended to use `:nnoremap`, this is one case where you have to allow remappings by using `:nmap`:

```
:nmap tn <C-w>h<cr>
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not helpful; what exactly happens instead?! Also, do the keys when typed individually by you achieve what you want? As romainl has pointed out, the `<C-w>h` isn't very solid, but it may work for your purposes.

Comment: i did it as the way you told me....when i typed "tn", it pop out the help window of(vi) on the top of mainwindow.

Comment: By the way, the above suggestion need to be modified to  "nmap tn:<C-w>h<cr>",or it will be invalid

Comment: Definitely not; your modification turns this into opening the help.

Comment: I add "nmap tn <C-w>h<cr>" in .vimrc.   I try it, nothing happened

Comment: For me, this jumps back to the beginning of the currently highlighted tag, as expected. If you really want the next tag, you'd need `nmap tn <C-w>hj<cr>`

Answer (score 3):

I don't use TagBar anymore so I can't test it for you but [the doc seems to say](https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar/blob/master/doc/tagbar.txt#L243) that you can use:

```
:TagbarOpen fj
```

to jump to the TagBar window. I think it is a little more solid than `<C-w>h` which is pretty much tied to a specific layout.

Thus, a possible mapping would be:

```
nnoremap tn :TagbarOpen fj<CR>
```

But neither your mapping nor this one allow you to place the cursor on the next tag which is what you seem to want (*"to jump to the next tag in the tagbar"*). TagBar has a mapping, `<C-n>` to go to the next top-level tag which may or may be not what you want. You could add it to the mix or, maybe, use `j`:

```
nnoremap tn :TagbarOpen fj<CR><C-n>
nnoremap tn :TagbarOpen fj<CR>j
```

---

As a side note, after a month of usage, I found TagBar to be rather good at showing the structure of my code but rather bad at helping me navigate through it. Because I used it primarily for navigation, I ditched it for Vim's default ctags integration (`<C-]>`, `:tag <Tab>`, `:tselect` and so on…) and CtrlP's wonderful `:CtrlPBufTag` and `:CtrlPTag`.

Comment: this doesn't work either. the main window keep still, even though the cusor in tagbar jump to the next tag

Comment: What does "keep still" mean? Do you want the tag under your cursor in TagBar to be displayed in the main window? Then add `<CR>` at the end of the mapping. If you want the cursor to stay in the TagBar window, add `p`.

Comment: What do you use besides Tagbar now?

Comment: @EhevuTov, it's in my answer: mostly CtrlP and vim's native tag-related commands. I don't use anything to show the structure of my code.